# conversion float to long in python

Tags: python, integer, long-integer

I have a function `fac(n)` which return `n!`, and I am comparing it to gamma(n+1)

```
>>> from math import gamma
>>> gamma(101)-fac(100)
0.0
>>> math.floor(gamma(101))-fac(100)
0.0
>>> long(gamma(101))-fac(100)
-1716052534060312817912314997891197522637580074354635372754659484313875350886868191008427848256820699487696649234627144617147818134104040275968L
```

gamma(101) = 100! and is an integer.

why are the results different ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results are different because of the limited precision of the floating point type, and because of the way the subtraction operator coerces its operands to be the same type.  The `gamma` function returns a float, so it cannot return an accurate answer for numbers this large.  [This page](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) gives a good description of the issues.

In `gamma(101)-fac(100)` the `fac(100)` term is converted to a float before the subtraction operation.

```
>>> gamma(101)
9.332621544394415e+157
>>> float(fac(100))
9.332621544394415e+157
```

The (most significant) part of `fac(100)` that fits in a float matches that of `gamma(101)`, so the subtraction results in `0.0`.

For your second test, `gamma(101)` has no fractional part so `math.floor` has no effect:

```
>>> math.floor(gamma(101)) == gamma(101)
True
```

When you convert `gamma(101)` to a long you can clearly see that it's inaccurate:

```
>>> long(gamma(101))
933262154439441509656467047959538825784009703731840988
310128895405822272385704312950661130892883272778258496
64006524270554535976289719382852181865895959724032L
>>> fac(100)
933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214
685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979
20827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000L
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers do not have infinite precision, and converting them to `long` will not give perfectly accurate results. The difference you're seeing is the difference between the floating point representation of `gamma(101)` and its actual integer value.

Comment: Strange inconsistency with the use of `math.floor` though -- it should theoretically return the same as the third.

Comment: @rfw: `math.floor()` returns a `float`; for an integral value stored as a float already, it's a no-op.

Comment: Weird, in Python 3 it returns `int` and `math.gamma` doesn't exist in Python 2.

Comment: `math.gamma` does exist in python 2. http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.gamma